# Getting an intermittent error while connecting to on-premise sql database from Azure service

Tags: azure, database-connection, hybrid

Created an azure MVC website, from service (controller) code we are connecting to an on-premise sql server using Azure Hybrid Connection. Intermittently we are facing below issue.

> "A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the
>   server. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The specified network name
>   is no longer available.)"

Please provide suggestions to resolve this issue.

Comment: have you solved the problem? We are having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can try following solutions :

Try increasing connection time-out.

check if remote connection is enabled.

Try adding firewall exception.

First of all the error means either the networks has some extra latency, the database is down or you may have too many concurrent connections open the database.

(Make sure you are closing all open datareaders.)

> also it may be due to [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/397573/intermittent-login-issues-to-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

These are transient faults and are to be expected in the cloud. Implementing defensive programming is usually a must in the cloud.  Try using some retry logic.  Microsoft's transient fault exception library is an excellent start.  Though meant primarily for SQL Azure and Azure Service bus, you can use the library for SQL IaaS.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, 98% sure, because I recently had the same experience, it is a network issue from the server provider.

For instance: if you are rent the server from Ionos, by default all remote connections are blocked, even though you disable the firewall in the server. You still won't be able to connect remotely. You can, however, do your work on the server without any problem.

To connect remotely, you have to contact the server provider. They will explain how to enable firewall ports from your control panel.

I contacted my server provider as I almost get frustrated. Here was their response.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6DUw.png)

After this, every permitted client can connect remotely to the server.

I wish you success.